# Linking HTML file and CSS file

Tags: python, html, css, flask, web

I am currently learning HTML and I was trying to create an external CSS file. But when I try to link them together I keep getting a 404 error saying that the css file cannot be found. Both the HTML and CSS file is in the same folder. I am using Notepad++.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">
</head>
<body>
<form>
<ul>
    <li><h1>Member Login</h1></li>
    <li><label for="fname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.."></li>
    <li>Password</li>
    <li>Submit</li>
    <li>Forgot Password</li>
</ul>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the files in your directory exactly?

Comment: I have 2 html files and a css file

Comment: What's the name of those files?

Comment: login; index; global

Comment: login and index are the 2 html files and global is the css file. I've checked each file properties to make sure they are html and css files respectively

Comment: Try doing a hard refresh on your browser. As for my approach, I tend to keep my stylesheets in a `/static` directory, where I can then just some Jinja `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='foo.css') }}"/>` but you shouldn't have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code from the third line

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">`

you forgot to add a back slash

```
'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css" />
```

Reference: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-link-css-to-html/

Comment: I added a backslash and it's still showing me a 404 error of css not being found.

Comment: Try giving the absolute path(you know C:\Users\XXX\XXX\myfirstwebsite\styles.css) of the css file. Also once again check if the css file is in a different folder than your html file. If it, great, if not you either move it to the same folder or give the absolute path.

Answer (score -1):

Type the path of the CSS file wherever you have saved it correctly in the html file.

```
 Hope it helps
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the closing tag in the link tag it should go

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css"/>
```

Comment: I just added it and it is still giving me a 404 error not found.